# How to run a plugin after all children are done in Webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, plugins, hook, webpack-4

In my Webpack configuration I have multiple processes with different configurations that I want to compile at the same time, so I export them like this:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = [clientConfig, serverConfig]
```

I currently have a basic custom plugin (a done hook that runs a shell command) that runs in one child, but the order of compilation isn't consistent and I would like to make sure it runs just once after all configurations are done compiling.

Is there a Webpack API or trick I can use to accomplish this?

**Edit:** To clarify, I do want to run this as a plugin so that it runs on each compilation in watch mode, so a batch command or shell script isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @rfcoder89 No unfortunately as I recall I just had to figure out a work around for my particular use case. Maybe this is possible in newer versions of Webpack than I was using at the time but I haven't tried.